# How to format text of option values inside of a select tag?

Tags: html, html-select

I have a list of table items that when a copy button is pressed, all the table items concatenate into one text box, get selected, and get put on windows clipboard.

Boxes are formatted like so:

```
<tr>
  <td>Name of Person:</td>
  <td><textarea name="name" rows="2" cols="30" id="name"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Type of Service:</td>
  <td><select name="drop1" id="txt_drop1">
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option value="Type of Service: Minimal">Minimal</option>
      <option value="Type of Service: Normal">Normal</option>
      <option value="Type of Service: Full">Full</option>
      <option value="Type of Service: Premium">Premium</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Dollar Amount:</td>
  <td><textarea name="amount" rows="1" cols="30" id="txt_info2"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><textarea name="bigtextbox" rows="5" cols="30" id="txt_info2"></textarea></td>
</tr>
```

What I need is the formatting, in that when the copy button is pressed, the resulting text concatenates in a neat manner. I can make it happen like so:


Name: John

Type of Service: Full

Amount: $125


But I also need to not line break if no option is selected in the drop down box, like so:

Name: John

Amount: $125


Instead of:

Name: John


Amount: $125

Is there a way to apply formatting code such as '\n' to the value of the option? Right now all my non  box textboxes are formatted in the concatenate code after the copy button is clicked, ex:

```
    <input type="button" style="font-weight:bold;" name="clipboard_copy" value="Copy" onClick="document.data_entry.bigtextbox.value = 'Name:&nbsp;' + document.data_entry.name.value + '\n' + document.data_entry.drop1.value + '\n' + 'Amount: $' + document.data_entry.amount.value>
```

Comment: You want some strange things... But as long as I know from HTML and select HTML Element, you can't format options like that (maybe I'm wrong). I'm sorry. If you want to do that, you will have to create your own select element with jQuery or something like that. I think is the best way to personalize your select, because you will work with `divs` and you can edit them more specifically

Comment: Sorry for making it strange, I just edited it to show more of what I'm looking for. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by creating my own select element. My actual application is a much much larger form that is used for my busniess, in which case every employee will use this form to create comments for clients accounts, and we need them to all be structured the same and look professional, which means I can not redo the whole form or anything, but if there is a quick way to fix this, I would be most delighted.

Comment: Our site just updated to IE8 and this is no longer working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably I didn't understand you. I thought you wanted to change `option` element format into the `select` element. If you want to achieve that format after pressing the button, you can try this:

```
<input type="button" style="font-weight:bold;" name="clipboard_copy" value="Copy"
onClick="document.data_entry.bigtextbox.value = 'Name:&nbsp;' + 
document.data_entry.name.value + (document.data_entry.drop1.value.trim().length 
=== 0) ? '' : '\n' + document.data_entry.drop1.value + '\n' + 'Amount: $' + 
document.data_entry.amount.value">
```

I added this line to your button example:

```
(document.data_entry.drop1.value.trim().length === 0) ? '' : '\n' + 
document.data_entry.drop1.value
```

This checks (you can check whatever condition you want. I just used this to check if you have selected "blank", for example) if your `select` has a value. If does not have a value, it sets `''` to your "response" text. If it contains something, it will add `'\n' + document.data_entry.drop1.value`.